# Android Internet connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, internet, android

I've recently downloaded Android x86 (Android 4.0) and installed it in [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) using using `android-x86-4.0-RC1-eeepc.iso`. Everything is working fine except the Internet connection. I've tried searching for a solution but none of them works for me.

I'm using a Samsung notebook with a wireless connection on Ubuntu 11.10.

Here's a screenshot of the network settings of the VirtualBox:

[image]

I've even tried with [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), but it still dosen't work.

Comment: Don't know much about android but your wifi connection will only work from VB if it is connected via USB

Comment: @BJ292 I've used similar settings for windows 7 in virtualbox and it works, not sure whats wrong with android settings.

Comment: There is a made for VBox version here that seems to work: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-run-android-4-0-ics-on-windows-mac-linux-using-virtualbox/  - I notice in VBox that networking is configured for port forwarding and in Android it shows Internet Not Connected but works anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one made for VirtualBox that seems to work, see *[How To Run Android 4.0 ICS On Windows, Mac & Linux Using VirtualBox](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-run-android-4-0-ics-on-windows-mac-linux-using-virtualbox/)*. I notice in VirtualBox that networking is configured for port forwarding and in Android it shows

> Internet Not Connected

but it works anyway.